# Where is the '.well-known' folder located?

Tags: assets, new-developer, verification, stellar.toml

Alright so I'm making an asset and trying to get the darn thing verified. My website is using GoDaddy for hosting. and it has Cpanel. I've got multiple questions.

First.
1. I have the stellar.toml file ready to go. I don't know where or how to add it to the website. I don't even know where the '.well-known' folder is. Do I have to make it?

2. How do I enable a CORS header?
   Do I add it above [[CURRENCY]] in the .Toml file or is their something I need to do in Cpanel?

There is a 2000 XLM reward for anyone who can help me <3

Comment: You should ask questions separately.  That way each one and its answers can be voted upon separately.  I suggest you edit this to a single question and then ask the other in another post.  Also, offering rewards is not the StackExchange way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have to create this folder.

[Stellar documentation](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/stellar-toml.html) explains it like this:
https://DOMAIN/.well-known/stellar.toml

Here is a real world example that you can try out:
https://stronghold.co/.well-known/stellar.toml

Comment: Upvoted. Thanks for the fast reply! So I make a sub folder on the Cpanel on godaddy named '.well-known'? How is a CORS added? I've read all the guides but it isn't clicking in my head lol.

Comment: CORS is not something you add to the file itself, it’s something you configure your server to tell the browser requesting the file that it is ok to load it from a different domain.

Answer (score 1):

1. .well-known is found inside the public_html directory on your server, put the stellar.toml file there.

Answer (score 0):

After creating your .well-known folder, don't forget to enable CORS on your Apache. If you don't have access to your apache.conf an .htaccess file would do. Just put it in your HTML folder with

```
<Location "/.well-known/stellar.toml">
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</Location>
```

Hope that helps.